# How to "import" NUnit tests from another assembly

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper

I have several assemblies in my project, each with a test assembly covering it (this cannot change, so don't suggest)

I have a common suite of tests that I want to be included in each test assembly's suite of tests.

I've put these common tests in their own assembly, and referenced this from each concrete test assembly, but NUnit/ReSharper test runners dont pick the tests up.

How can I make NUnit and ReSharper test runners include/find these common tests for each test assembly, and execute them?

**Update:** Currently both my common and per-project tests are simply defined with `[TestFixture]` and `[Test]` Attributes

**Examples**

example test from common assembly

```
namespace Example.Common {
    [Test]
    public void CommonTest() {
        // something that applys to all assemblies, like code analysis, obviously this is a silly example, but the contents of the test is not important. I just want this included with the other tests in the specific assemblies
        Assert.AreEqual(10, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes.Count());
    }
}
```

example test from project-specific assembly:

```
namespace Example.Specific {
    [Test]
    public void SpecificTest() {
        // something specific to this assembly
        Assert.AreEqual("Example.Specific", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
    }
}
```

I want the common test to be included in the

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you'd give a short but complete example of exactly what you're doing. (Are you using [`SuiteAttribute`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.6.3), for example?)

Comment: @jonSkeet I'm not, although that appears to need manual registration which id rather avoid. I realise I could reflect, and then inherit from the suite, but that all seems rather hacky, thought I must be missing some trick

Comment: Well it's hard to say what you're missing when we can't see what you're trying to do. If we could reproduce it ourselves, we could help you...

Answer (score 2):

You need to have derived classes of your `CommonTest` classes. It is not enough to just reference the common test assembly. Earlier this year I was faced with the same problem; I wanted to execute several tests, but with a difference configuration (app.config). In the end it is the same problem, but unfortunately, there is no easy way like a `[assembly: IncludeTest( typeof(CommonTest))]`.. That would be awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand you correctly, but here is what I would do:

- Have a library which would contain class with all the common tests, something like:

```cs
namespace NUnitCommon
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class NUnitCommonTestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void CommonTestNoOne()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

- Then you should include reference to this library in each of your "specific" test projects and have all the test classes to inherit from it:

```cs
using NUnitCommon;

namespace NUnitSpecific
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SpecificTestClass : NUnitCommonTestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void SpecificTestNoOne()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

That way if you would run all the tests for `SpecificTestClass`, also the tests from `NUnitCommonTestClass` would be run. Tested using ReSharper. Is that what you want? If not, please clarify.

Comment: Doing it this way will most likely cause unintended results. Marking `NUnitCommonTestClass` as a `[TestFixture]` then allow `SpecificTestClass` to inherit from it will allow your test suite to run all of the tests in the base class multiple times. For eg: if the base class has 10 tests and the child class has 10 tests, the total number of tests that will be run is 10 from the base class + 10 from the child class running the base class' tests + 10 from the child class itself = 30 tests. My guess is you want 20 tests to run not 30. To fix that the OP should make the base class an abstract class.

Comment: @Quinn that will only happen if you run all the tests from both the base class assembly and from child class assembly which you can avoid quite easily. So I really dont understand your point, neither the downvote as the other answer provides the same guidance as mine. Just to make sure - do you realize the base class is in its own assembly, right?